# Multiply vector by matrix

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

How can I multiply RealVector by matrix (v*M) in apache-commons-math library? I found only multiply Matrix by Matrix and Matrix by RealVector.

Comment: What result do you expect when you would multiply a vector with a matrix? Hint: it can't be done: http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication. If your matrix is one-dimension anyway, consider conversion to a vector.

Comment: I need multiply [x,y,z,1] by 4*4 matrix for affine transformation, so I expect a new vector eg [x,y,0,w]

Comment: @Munchhausen This is possible, if the vector is a row vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preMultiply`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html#preMultiply(org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector)) seems to be the method you're looking for.

```
RealVector vector = ...
RealMatrix matrix = ...
RealVector result = matrix.preMultiply(vector);
```